# Set TextView when EditText is changed - Shopping cart

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

In Cart I am displaying all objects in a `Tableview`  [image]

When I change the quantity in `EditText` its corresponding row total in `TextView` should be changed. I've tried to achieve this using `addTextChangedListener` , `TextWatcher` and in many ways but it is changing the text of last row total(`TextView`).

`TableLayout` code:

```
for(i=0;i<cartSize;i++)
            {
            pName    = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductName();
            pPrice  = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductPrice();

            final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            product = new TextView(this);
            product.setText(pName);
            product.setId(i);
            product.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            product.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(product);

            price = new TextView(this);
            price.setText(pPrice);
            price.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            price.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(price);

            QTY = new EditText(this);
            QTY.setText("1");
            QTY.setId(i);
            QTY.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            QTY.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            QTY.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            int maxLength = 6;
            InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
            fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
            QTY.setFilters(fArray);
            QTY.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    int tot = 1;
                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                        total.setText("0");


                    } else {
                        int a = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                        tot = Integer.parseInt(pPrice) * a;
                        total.setText("" + tot);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            tr.addView(QTY);

            total = new TextView(this);
            total.setId(i);
            total.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            total.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            total.setText(pPrice);


            tr.addView(total);

            select = new CheckBox(this);
            select.setChecked(true);
            select.setId(i);
            select.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(select));
            tr.addView(select);

            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

How to change total now..